# Finding largest square less than a given number in Java

Tags: java, math.sqrt

I want to write a java program to find the **largest square number** which is less than or equal to a given number.

> For example when I insert `10` as the inputted number, the answer is `9` because `9`is the **largest square** up to `10`

I understand loops, but I can't figure out the logic behind this one.

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do this with loops

```
int n=10; //This is your Number
int i = 0;
for(i=n;i>=1;i--)
    if((int)Math.sqrt(i)*(int)Math.sqrt(i)==i)
        break;
System.out.println(i);
```

**Below is how it works**:-

The Loop runs from the `n`, which is your number, to `1`. It then checks whether, the square root of `i`, which is running through `n` to `1`, is a `perfect square`. If it is, it `breaks` the `loop`, and prints the value of `i` on the screen.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful

Comment: @kago If it helped, please select it as the answer.

Comment: i just did thank you

Answer (score 2):

How about something like the following to get you going ...

```
double x = 20;
double root = Math.sqrt(x);
int t = (int)root;
System.out.println("Root is:" + root + " and answer is :" + t*t);
```

Comment: This is the way to go IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        System.out.println(largestSquareLessOrEqualTo(145)); 
    } 

    public static int largestSquareLessOrEqualTo(int limit){
    int i = 0;
        for (; i <(int)Math.sqrt(limit); i++){
        }
        return(i*i);
    }
```